# Arrange multiple plots with ggarrange in for loop

Tags: r, plot

I would like to arrange multiple plots in one image with the following code:

```
mydataframe <- data.frame(
  number1 = sample(1:140, size=200, replace=TRUE),
  number2 = sample(1:4000, size=200, replace=TRUE),
  number3 = sample(1:30, size=200, replace=TRUE),
  number4 = sample(1:200, size=200, replace=TRUE)
)

unit <- c(
  "number1" = "kmh", 
  "number2" = "rpm", 
  "number3" = "degrees", 
  "number4" = "volts"
)

labels <- c(
  "number1" = "Number 1", 
  "number2" = "Number 2", 
  "number3" = "Number 3", 
  "number4" = "Number 4"
)

for(key in names(unit))
{
  c_plot <- paste0 ("plot_", key) # generate new variable per plot
  
  assign (c_plot, # assign current plot to new variable
          
          ggplot(mydataframe, aes(x=key, y=eval(parse(text = key)))) +
            geom_boxplot() +
            labs (x = labels[key], y = unit[key]) +
            theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
  )
  
  ggsave(filename = paste0("plots/", key, ".jpg"), plot = eval(parse(text = c_plot))) # save current plot as single image - that works
}

allplots <- ggarrange(plot_number1, plot_number2, plot_number3, plot_number4, # arrange all 4 plots - plot is always the last one generated
                      labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                      ncol = 2, nrow = 2)

allplots
```

As a result I get an image with 4 plots (what is correct), the label of x and y axis is correctly assigned (f.e. number1 for x and mph for y axis), but everything else is 4 times the last plot - the same data with same boxplots and the same y scales.

The strange thing is that the images saved with ggsave (which saves the current plot) is performed correctly - every single plot is created with the correct data and is different from all other plots.

Has anyone an idea what I do wrong? It seems that a specific part of the code in the for loop is not unified to the variable "c_plot" and is overwritten at the end of the loop, so in the end the data of the last plot is used for all plots.

Comment: I suspect this is a lazy evaluation problem, but without your input data I can't test my hypothesis.  `for` loops use lazy evaluation, so the value of `key` when `ggarrange` is called is `volts`, so `plot_number_<x>` all evaluate to the same thing.  To see if this is what is happening (and to fix the problem), change from using a `for` loop to one of the `apply` family of functions: these *force* evaluation and so avoid the problem.

Comment: Hi!
Really many thanks for your answer. I edited my question and supplied a dataframe. I hope this is suitable for you. Could you maybe help me again what you mean with the "apply family"? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was right.  It's a lazy evaluation problem.

The "apply" family of functions, including, `sapply`, `lapply` and `mapply`, apply a function to series of values.  See the online help.

Next time, please indicate which packages your code requires so that you provide a self-contained, *reproducible* example.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

plotList <- lapply(
              names(unit),
              function(key) {
                # Need to assign the plot to a variable because 
                # you want to generate the plot AND save to file 
                x <- ggplot(mydataframe, aes(x=key, y=eval(parse(text = key)))) +
                       geom_boxplot() +
                       labs (x = labels[key], y = unit[key]) +
                       theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
                # No need for the plot argument.  It defaults to the last plot created.
                ggsave(filename = paste0("plots/", key, ".jpg"))
                # Return the plot just created
                x
              }
)

allplots <- ggarrange(plotlist=plotList,
                      labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                      ncol = 2, nrow = 2)

allplots
```

Giving

[image]

Answer (score 0):

using the approach @Limey

```r
mydataframe <- data.frame(
  number1 = sample(1:140, size=200, replace=TRUE),
  number2 = sample(1:4000, size=200, replace=TRUE),
  number3 = sample(1:30, size=200, replace=TRUE),
  number4 = sample(1:200, size=200, replace=TRUE)
)

unit <- c(
  "number1" = "kmh", 
  "number2" = "rpm", 
  "number3" = "degrees", 
  "number4" = "volts"
)

labels <- c(
  "number1" = "Number 1", 
  "number2" = "Number 2", 
  "number3" = "Number 3", 
  "number4" = "Number 4"
)

library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
plotList <- imap(unit, ~ggplot(mydataframe, aes(x = !!sym(.y))) +
       labs(x = .x, y = labels[.y]) +
       geom_boxplot() +
       coord_flip())

ggarrange(plotlist = plotList, labels = LETTERS[1:4])
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you too for your solution! The code looks really great - if you have time I would like to learn more about the commands you use - could you maybe comment on the code, what imap and the "sym" with the "!!" does?

Comment: my English is too bad for a good explanation. Have you looked at the help for the commands  ?`!!`, ?`imap`?

Comment: If you believe this answer was helpful for you, you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of this answer :)